# Encode File present on s3 aws to sha1 base64 encoding

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encoding, base64, sha1

I want to encode the file already uploaded at s3. So i want to create encode string sha1 base64. So is there any way to create it??

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done 'on' S3.

You would need to download the file, encode it, then upload it.

Comment: Is there any way to hash and encode the file without taking the file in memory via stream or something else

Comment: Something will need to retrieve the data from S3, process it and upload it again. Whether you do this "in memory" or via disk is up to you. You could do it from an Amazon EC2 instance, an AWS Lambda function or even your own computer -- but it can't be done by S3 itself.